# Python extract A inner attribute data-display-name

Tags: python, href

I am trying to extract "data-display-name"  inside the following html code but cannot seem to find the right xpath.

```
<a href="/nl/v/plutosport-nl/930267/?offerId=1001033806579406" class="js_buy_block_seller_popup" style="color: inherit; text-decoration: none;" data-display-name="Plutosport.nl" data-id="930267" .......
</a>
```

I get an error if I use the following

```
seller = t.xpath('//div[@class="buy-block__seller-name"]/a/@data-display-name').strip()
```

Although getting the href works fine with this line

```
seller_href = t.xpath(''//div[@class="buy-block__seller-name"]/a/@href').strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = 'data-display-name'
seller = t.xpath('//div[@class="buy-block__seller-name"]/a[@title="$title"]/text()', title=name)
print(seller)
```

Try this